# How to get company license for windows 8 Apps developed in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, appx

we developed Windows 8 based application using Visual Studio 2012. when I create package using Create App package in store of visual studio 2012.  Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 and other supporting packages generated.
Customer tries to install Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 using power shell. It require Microsoft account   to get one month developer license. But we need a full time company license for customer.
How can we get company license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no company licence available. You have to renew it each month by just doing login via Live account.

Comment: what if there are more then 500 customers, all are needed to create there live account to renew licence.?

Comment: No single Live account can have multiple developer licence.